# Spark SQL HiveContext - saveAsTable creates wrong schema

Tags: hive, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to store a Dataframe to a persistent Hive table in Spark 1.3.0 (PySpark). This is my code:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="HiveTest")
hc = HiveContext(sc)
peopleRDD = sc.parallelize(['{"name":"Yin","age":30}'])
peopleDF = hc.jsonRDD(peopleRDD)
peopleDF.printSchema()
#root
# |-- age: long (nullable = true)
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
peopleDF.saveAsTable("peopleHive")
```

The Hive output table I expect is:

```
Column  Data Type   Comments
age     long        from deserializer
name    string      from deserializer
```

But the actual output Hive table of the above code is:

```
Column  Data Type       Comments
col     array<string>   from deserializer
```

Why is the Hive table not the same schema as the DataFrame? How to achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the schema is wrong. Hive is not able to correctly read table created by Spark, because it doesn't even have the right parquet serde yet. 
If you do `sqlCtx.sql('desc peopleHive').show()`, it should show the correct schema.
Or you can use the spark-sql client instead of hive. You can also use the create table syntax to create external tables, which works just like Hive, but Spark has much better support for parquet.

Comment: True, `hc.sql('desc peopleHive').show()` shows the correct schema.
I misunderstood the Spark documentation. I believed that saveAsTable does create a Hive table that can be used from outside Spark. I understand now that this is not the case. To achieve this I need to run  `peopleDF.registerTempTable("peopleHive")
hc.sql('create table peopleHive as select name, age from peopleHive')`

Comment: It is a way of adding rows to this table? Or I must use a partition? There is a way or specify the correct `serde` en `saveAsTable` so `Imapala` or `Hive` can read it?

Comment: @nanounanue, 1) yes there is a way to add rows to an existing table, and you don't need to use partitions: `hc.sql('insert into table peopleHive select name, age from peopleHive')`. 2) I haven't found a way to use `saveAsTable()` so that Hive can read it. Please let me know if you do.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for override like behaviour would be

```scala
val viewName = "tempView"
df.createTempView(viewName)

df.sparkSession.sql(s"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${tableName}")
df.sparkSession.sql(
  s"""CREATE TABLE $tableName AS
    | select * from $viewName
  """.stripMargin)

df.sparkSession.catalog.dropTempView(viewName)
```